# Retrieve imaged saved in DB

Tags: php, database, image, laravel, display

I have the following problem:
Path of image is being stored to DB, but the actual file in Storage folder as a complete different name and I can't find a way to retrieve to display in view:

public function savePicture(Request $request){

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $image_path = $request->file('image')->store('public');
    $image = Image::make(Storage::get($image_path))->resize(320,240)->encode();
    Storage::put($image_path,$image);
    $image_path = explode('/',$image_path);
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $user->image = Storage::url($image_name);
    $user->save();
    return back();
} else{
    return "No file selected";
}
```

This is the Query to get the path, but cant make it work, because its an object and $pic->image not working in view

```
$imagen = DB::table('users')
            ->select('image')
            ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id);

return view('/tablero', [
  'posts' => $posts,
  'pic' => $image,
  ]);
```

My Database loos like

image: /storage/name.png

But in my Storage folder I get d7f7r87RmMy4NtCFvbJ8sQeutfC5wtsiak7GZXcn.png

I've been trying different ways to display the Image but it's not working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the file in the database using the file's Original Name, but saving in the storage directory under the name that's returned to you by the store method. So you could do

```
$user->image = $image_path;
```

instead of

```
$user->image = Storage::url($image_name);
```

OR if you want to save the file's original name into both the db and storage you could do

```
Storage::put($image_name, $image);
$user->image = Storage::url($image_name);
```

Comment: Got it! Posted below. Now Im struggling to get the path from DB, which saved the hashed name of the pic.

When I do the following:

    $imagen = DB::table('users')
                ->select('imagen')
                ->where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->pluck('imagen');

I get this result in view:

 ["\/storage\/YEWXYIHXGWJUmYcDeWBoEO1EbqP7jBE2phOwFr83.png"]

But it's not working to retrieve image with img src '''

Comment: Use `<img src="{{ asset('your file path') }}" >` to display the image

Comment: When I do that, my file path is:
"\/storage\/YEWXYIHXGWJUmYcDeWBoEO1EbqP7jBE2phOwFr83.png"
Im not sure where the \ is coming from, because it's not in the DB, and Im unable to retrieve the picture. Also Im haivng troubles calling a variable beetween {{}}

Comment: What trouble to call variable between blade syntax?

Comment: I was getting this as result from query ["\/storage\/YEWXYIHXGWJUmYcDeWBoEO1EbqP7jBE2phOwFr83.png"]

I couldnt find out why, so I ended up doing this monstruosity 
    $imagen = DB::table('users')
                ->select('imagen')
                ->where('id', '=', $user_id)
                ->pluck('imagen');
    $imagen= substr($imagen, 3, -2);

I manually deleted the things I didnt need from $imagen and its working

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need to add $image_name to the path.

i.e.

```
$image_path = $image_path . '/'. $image_name;
```

Before you do

```
Storage::put($image_path,$image);
```

Comment: Changed $image_name = $request->image->hashName(); I was saving the Users file name instead of using the hashed instance of Laravel. Now its saving properly into the DB, but Im still trying to figure out how to display the path in img src

Answer (score 0):

Using the store() method Laravel generates a random name for the file. You should use the storeAs() method which lets you provide the name you want to save the file by.

```
$image_name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$image_path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('path/to/storage', $image_name);
```